# Configure IIS for ftp using Visual Studio for an asp.net application in windows 7

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis, configuration, windows-7

HI

can anyone please tell me how to do this please? I can't seem to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been impressed with the built-in Microsoft FTP server, no matter what version of IIS you are using. I would recommend using FileZilla Server as a more secure alternative. That being said, VS does not support encrypted ftp such as ftps or sftp. If you need to use ftp to manage a site I would do this outside of VS.

That being said the link below will get you started managing websites in VS 2008:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/387/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis-70/